# Responsive issue : image (float left) and div -> image (center) and div under

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-float

I've a small issue. I've an image with `float: left;` and then a div with text. The result is something like that : https://css-tricks.com/wp-content/csstricks-uploads/web-text-wrap.png

Which is great. But when the screen got smaller, at the end, because the image is only 250px large, there's the image on the left and few words on the right. I would like to "push" the div with test under the image and center the image at the same time : when the screen is, for example 400px large.

How can I do this !? It seems quite easy, but all the tutos or codepen I tried just confused me...

Thanks

Comment: Do you have your markup and the relevant CSS to show us?

Answer (score 0):

Research [media tags](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) I think they are exactly what you are looking for.

So your css would go something like this:

```
@media all (width: 400px){
    .image{
        ...
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: Uhh, there is no such thing as `position: center`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Constantly Confused and smoggers.

I used smoggers' code, didn't worked as expected, but was a perfect base to try and find solution :

```
.images {float: left;}


@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .images {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
  }
}
```

Thanks again.